# how do I filter a view in SharePoint based on last year?

Tags: list, filter, view

I need to create a view with only last year, 2014, data showing. 
I tried creating calculated columns for start and end date and using less than start date and greater than end date filter in the view, but this is not working for me. I need to show 2014 items only.

Answer (score 0):

Max,

You can use a date filter web part. Here are step-by-step instructions. Let me know if you have any questions.

[SharePoint: List filtering by date range](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/08/18/sharepoint-list-filtering-by-date-range-aspx/)

Here's another how-to.

[Filter List Using Date Range of a Column in SharePoint](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8e86c/filter-list-using-date-range-of-a-column-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: jpollar, you could improve your answer, by adding some excerpt from detailed answer just in case your link becomes broken.